# NGINX ingress pod log showing worker node ip as origin

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a network policy which will allow connection only from my IP address to the NGINX ingress controller. The network policy is given below. The ingress is using a load balancer and app is in different namespace (default).

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-access
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: nginx-ingress
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 11.11.11.11/32
    ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: http
      - protocol: TCP
        port: https
```

But after deploying the network policy I can't establish a connection to my application. So I have changed the CIDR range from 11.11.11.11/32 to 0.0.0.0/0 and checked the logs to see from which IP address I am receiving the connection.

> 22.22.22.22 - - [10/Nov/2022:05:14:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7250 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
> 462 0.006 [default-hello-one-80] [] 10.2.0.6:80 7243 0.004 200
> 4d3fd980e5d07a084b162c1f9305f2d9

It means I am getting hit by one of my kubernetes worker node. (22.22.22.22)

I tried adding all worker node IP address and load balancer IP address under ipBlock, but still my application is not accessible.can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` on the Ingress controller service.

Documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip)

Setting this allows the original client IP (which would be outside the cluster) to be preserved, so things like allow/deny list sand networkpolicies would work properly.

Comment: Hi Blender Fox, thank for your update, as you mentioned I changed my service
type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
but now the application is accessible form all IP address

Comment: That looks like it might not be picking up your NetworkPolicy properly. I can't advise on that since I've never used it. But I do use the whitelist-source-range annotation to block outside ranges: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range.

Comment: Additionally, you could utilise the `loadBalancerSourceRanges` feature (See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) which blocks at the network level (traffic outside of the ranges would never even make it to the  cluster and would just timeout)